# Accessing Ubuntu Server from a Windows Machine?

Tags: ssh, remote

I just bought a PowerEdge 1850, it's great and doing exactly what I need it to do but it's loud so I've placed it into my attic. The only trouble is every time I need to make a change or install new software I have to climb up there to access the machine.

I tried to use PuTTY but I get connection refused and no other hardware is using the same IP as the machine. All I want to be able to do is to remote access the terminal from my desktop PC in my room so I can install new software and run commands as if I was at my server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install openssh-server in order to connect via SSH (e.g. using PuTTY):

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```